# Push Notification not being displayed on a physical phone

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am using parse for my push notification, and the push notification works fine on emulators, but doesn't work on a physical device or a tablet.

Below is the code is used into the system:

```
     ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

                 // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
                 PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Activity.class, R.drawable.ic);
                    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

 <uses-permission android:name="com.dooba.beta.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />




       <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Below is some manif code that deals with permission: 


         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.dooba.beta.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.dooba.beta.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```